# mysql join: get parts with count for each type

Tags: php, mysql, join, count

I have two tables:

1) parts

```
part_id  |  part_name
```

2) posts

```
post_id | part_id | type | title | content
```

in posts table the post has one of three types, so in type column I put value (1 or 2 or 3)

I want to get table (with count and join) like this

```
part_id | part_name | count_posts_type1 | count_posts_type2 | count_posts_type3
```

how to do this with mysql?

example:

[image]

Comment: what is common between these 2 tables?

Comment: common is part_id I fixed it

Comment: I added an example for results I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using sum with case when is a rather common way to do this if you have a limited list of types.

Then a left join to have result for parts without post (and a coalesce to have 0 instead of null on sums), and here we go.

```
select 
pa.part_id, pa.part_name,
coalesce(sum(case when po.type = 1 then 1 else 0 end), 0) as count_posts_type1,
coalesce(sum(case when po.type = 2 then 1 else 0 end), 0) as count_posts_type2,
coalesce(sum(case when po.type = 3 then 1 else 0 end), 0) as count_posts_type3
from parts pa
left join posts po on po.part_id = pa.part_id
group by pa.part_id, pa.part_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like (just joking, I know you tried nothing) something like:

```
SELECT
     parts.part_id,
     parts.part_name,
     COUNT(t1.post_id) AS count_posts_type1,
     COUNT(t2.post_id) AS  count_posts_type2,
     COUNT(t3.post_id) AS count_posts_type3
FROM posts
     RIGHT JOIN part ON posts.part_id=parts.part_id 
     INNER JOIN ( SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE type=1 ) as t1(post_id) ON posts.post_id = t1.post_id
     INNER JOIN ( SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE type=1 ) as t2(post_id) ON posts.post_id = t2.post_id
     INNER JOIN ( SELECT post_id FROM posts WHERE type=1 ) as t3(post_id) ON posts.post_id = t3.post_id
```